# How to change a SQL query into PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have 3 tables.

driver, trip, tripLegs

In driver table the columns are E#, L#, STATUS.
In trip table the columns are T#, L#, REG#, trip_DATE
In tripLeg table the columns are T#, LEG#, DEPARTURE, DESTINATION

First I tried a sql query which is:

```
select d.l#, count(tg.leg#) as total_no_of_legs
from driver d left outer join trip t on (d.l# = t.l#)
left outer join tripleg tg on (t.t# = tg.t#)
group by d.l#;
```

Results i got was:

```
L#         Total_no_of_legs
-----------------------------
11111        20
```

and so on.

This is the total number of legs from all T#'s leg#
e.g

```
T#1 's leg# = 3
T#2's leg# = 10
T#3's leg# = 7
```

Total = 20 that is why L# 11111 total no of Legs is 20.
But I wanna find out the max leg# of each L# which is 10.
How do I do a query to find out highest number of LEG# group by T#?

Afterwhich, how do I really start to convert this into a PL/SQL statement?

Have been wondering all day and reading up on books. Still couldnt find a solution to it

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*convert this into a PL/SQL statement*". Do you want to write a function that returns this result? A stored procedure that uses this result?

Comment: why do you want it a PL/SQL statement? You need it in a function or in a procedure?

Comment: Yes a I want to write a PL/SQL stored that shows this result

Comment: Again, why do you want a stored proc? What's wrong with a query? [Stored procs are to be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516088/when-to-use-a-stored-procedure-mysql/8516334#8516334)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *But I wanna find out the max leg# of each L#*

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't that simply:

```
select d.l#, 
       max(tg.leg#) as max_leg_nr
from driver d 
  left outer join trip t on (d.l# = t.l#)
  left outer join tripleg tg on (t.t# = tg.t#)
group by d.l#
```

I don't see the need to put this into a stored procedure.

To put this into a function that returns the result, you need a pipelined function:

```
create type leg_info as object (l# integer, max_leg_nr integer);
/

create type leg_info_list as table of leg_info
/

create or replace function get_max_leg_info
  return leg_info_list
  PIPELINED
as
  r_info leg_info;
begin
   r_info := leg_info(null, null);
   for p_rec in ( .... here goes the select ... )
   loop
     r_info.l# := p_rec.l#;
     r_info.max_leg_nr := p_rec.max_leg_nr ;
     pipe row(r_row);
   end loop;
   return;
end;
/
```

You can then use this function like this:

```
select *
from table(get_max_leg_info())
```

Comment: I don't see a need too but I am doing this because I am learning PL/SQL stored function. Trying to study for my exams and came up with this. Need to understand before exams come. Please that if you could help

Comment: My actual goal is to use a stored function with a parameter in the function , using select statement to list the l# together with the length of the longest trip performed by each l#

Comment: @RusydiRusydii: so you want a function that returns those results?